# Unexpected token } in JSON at position 378

Tags: json

Trying to figure out why the top .json file returns an error while the bottom works fine. (sorry if format is terrible, first post here) working code is from GitHub so i don't have very much knowledge of the 'inner workings'(mac OS). TIA

```
{
  "regions": [
    "cville",
    "tech",
    "downtown",
    "outskirts",
    "allregions"

  ],

  "region_subregions": {
    "cville": ["tech", "downtown"],
     "allregions": ["cville", "tech", "downtown", "northcv",  "southcv", "westcv", "canecreek"]

  },
  "region_neighborhoods": {
    "southcv": ["parkview", "sink", "fairground"],    

  }
}


{
  "regions": [
    "sf",
    "eastsf",
    "centralsf",
    "westsf",
    "southsf",
    "peninsula",
    "sanjose",
    "marin",
    "eastbay",
    "sacramento",
    "allregions"
  ],
  "region_subregions": {
    "sf": ["eastsf", "centralsf", "westsf"],
    "allregions": ["eastsf", "centralsf", "westsf", "southsf", "peninsula", "sanjose", "marin", "eastbay", "sacramento"]
  },
  "region_neighborhoods": {
    "eastsf": ["embarcadero-p39-northbeach", "missionbay-dogpatch", "soma-ferry_bldg", "fidi-union_sq", "tenderloin-civic_center", "nob-russian_hill"],
    "centralsf": ["haight-castro", "mission-dolores", "fillmore-hayes_valley"],
    "westsf": ["presidio-marina", "richmond-gg_park", "sunset-", "lakeview-lake_merced"],
    "southsf": ["glen_park-twin_peaks", "ingleside-", "excelsior-portola", "outer_mission-cow_palace", "bayview-", "south_city-brisbane", "daly_city-pacifica"],
    "peninsula": ["half_moon_bay-coast", "san_bruno-burlingame", "san_mateo-foster_city", "belmont-sc-rws", "redwood_city-palo_alto", "mt-view_sunnyvale"],
    "sanjose": ["san-jose"],
    "marin": ["marin-"],
    "eastbay": ["oakland-", "berkeley-", "east-bay"],
    "sacramento": ["sacramento-"]
  }
}
```

Comment: http://jsonlint.com is useful at diagnosing this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the trailing comma on this line

```
 "southcv": ["parkview", "sink", "fairground"],
```